# Kubernetes repository Fail

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm, centos7

When I try To deploy Kubernetes cluster on centos 7 server ,i got below error so i try to deploy a different server same error happen ,so kindly help me to fix this issue

[image]

Comment: You should first check your yum transaction history to get the exact details using the "yum history" command.

Comment: Are you running this on GCP cloud or a standalone machine/VM ? Please also update your question with reproduction steps to make any troubleshooting possible.

Comment: its vm machines

Comment: Please post reproductions teps or at least describe in steps what are you doing and getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

Adding **Kubernetes** repo with the below command in RockyLinux 8 (Like CentOS 8) worked for me!

```bash
# adding google kubernetes repository for amd64 (x86_64) architecture
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo
[kubernetes]
name=Kubernetes
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
EOF
```

Run this command to check `yum search kubeadm`